# Evaluating a cross over design with a very strong carry-over effect

Tags: mixed-model, crossover-study

I'm wondering how to properly evaluate a trial which was performed using a cross-over design evaluating two instruction techniques. Group A is instructed by technique 1, Group B by technique 2, both perform the exam and we consider the percentage of correctly answered questions- and afterwards it's the other way round (but with the same exam!).

So, naturally there has been a strong learning effect already from the first to the second period and I don't think that it is possible to examine a "treatment" effect in the second period, because we can't separate the period (=learning) effect from it.

I thought about modelling these effects (and I did this) but always end up in only analyzing the data from the first period for the main research question. So I would be interested in your opinion on that as I'm quite unexperienced with this type of study.

Thanks!